# Oracle XMLDOM.GetNodeValue sometimes return null

Tags: xml, oracle

I have the following code to parse a `CLOB` variable containing XML elements and store it into a variable. Code is as follows:

```
DECLARE
    myinput CLOB;
    userId VARCHAR2(100);
    xmlDoc xmldom.DOMDocument;
    xmlRootNode xmldom.DOMNode;
    xmlRowList xmldom.DOMNodeList;
    xmlRow xmldom.DOMElement;
    rowNo VARCHAR2(8);
    stfNo VARCHAR2(6);
    modC    VARCHAR2(12);
    coordTpC   VARCHAR2(4);
    coordRemark  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    myinput := '<NewDataSet><Table1><RowNo>1</RowNo><STF_N>STF_1</STF_N><MOD_C>MOD_1</MOD_C><COORD_TP_C>COORD_1</COORD_TP_C><COORD_REMARK>REMARK_1</COORD_REMARK></Table1><Table1><RowNo>2</RowNo><STF_N>STF_2</STF_N><MOD_C>MOD_2</MOD_C><COORD_TP_C>COORD_2</COORD_TP_C><COORD_REMARK>REMARK_2</COORD_REMARK></Table1><Table1><RowNo>3</RowNo><STF_N>STF_3</STF_N><MOD_C>MOD_3</MOD_C><COORD_TP_C>COORD_3</COORD_TP_C><COORD_REMARK>REMARK_3</COORD_REMARK></Table1><Table1><RowNo>4</RowNo><STF_N>STF_4</STF_N><MOD_C>MOD_4</MOD_C><COORD_TP_C>COORD_4</COORD_TP_C><COORD_REMARK>REMARK_4</COORD_REMARK></Table1></NewDataSet>';

    xmlDoc := UI20_PKG_QETAdm.parse(myinput);
    xmlRootNode := xmldom.MAKENODE(xmldom.getDocumentElement(xmlDoc));
    xmlRowList := xmldom.GETCHILDNODES(xmlRootNode);

    FOR rowCount IN 0 .. (xmldom.GETLENGTH(xmlRowList) - 1) LOOP
        xmlRow := xmldom.makeElement(xmldom.item(xmlRowList, rowCount));
        rowNo := xmldom.GETNODEVALUE(xmldom.GETFIRSTCHILD((xmldom.item(xmldom.getElementsByTagName(xmlRow, 'RowNo'), 0))));
        stfNo := xmldom.GETNODEVALUE(xmldom.GETFIRSTCHILD((xmldom.item(xmldom.getElementsByTagName(xmlRow, 'STF_N'), ''))));
        modC := xmldom.GETNODEVALUE(xmldom.GETFIRSTCHILD((xmldom.item(xmldom.getElementsByTagName(xmlRow, 'MOD_C'), ''))));
        coordTpC := xmldom.GETNODEVALUE(xmldom.GETFIRSTCHILD((xmldom.item(xmldom.getElementsByTagName(xmlRow, 'COORD_TP_C'), ''))));
        coordRemark := xmldom.GETNODEVALUE(xmldom.GETFIRSTCHILD((xmldom.item(xmldom.getElementsByTagName(xmlRow, 'COORD_REMARK'), ''))));

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('rowNo ' || rowNo);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('stfNo ' || stfNo);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('modC ' || modC);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('coordTpC ' || coordTpC);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('coordRemark ' || coordRemark);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

But I'm getting empty for all `rowNo,stfNo,modC,coordTpC,coordRemark`. And it is very weird that in some occasion, my SP can read the value, but on sometime later, it will complain that the value is NULL. What are the factors that can cause this?

I tried to use OracleSQLDeveloper, and this is the output I'm getting from the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` command

```
rowNo 1
stfNo 
modC 
coordTpC 
coordRemark 
rowNo 2
stfNo 
modC 
coordTpC 
coordRemark 
rowNo 3
stfNo 
modC 
coordTpC 
coordRemark 
rowNo 4
stfNo 
modC 
coordTpC 
coordRemark
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestion would be a select-statement where you use bulk collect to get the variables. I wrote the select to show you what I mean:

```
with the as (select xmltype('<NewDataSet><Table1><RowNo>1</RowNo><STF_N>STF_1</STF_N><MOD_C>MOD_1</MOD_C><COORD_TP_C>COORD_1</COORD_TP_C><COORD_REMARK>REMARK_1</COORD_REMARK></Table1><Table1><RowNo>2</RowNo><STF_N>STF_2</STF_N><MOD_C>MOD_2</MOD_C><COORD_TP_C>COORD_2</COORD_TP_C><COORD_REMARK>REMARK_2</COORD_REMARK></Table1><Table1><RowNo>3</RowNo><STF_N>STF_3</STF_N><MOD_C>MOD_3</MOD_C><COORD_TP_C>COORD_3</COORD_TP_C><COORD_REMARK>REMARK_3</COORD_REMARK></Table1><Table1><RowNo>4</RowNo><STF_N>STF_4</STF_N><MOD_C>MOD_4</MOD_C><COORD_TP_C>COORD_4</COORD_TP_C><COORD_REMARK>REMARK_4</COORD_REMARK></Table1></NewDataSet>') xml_ from dual) 
select tt.*
    from the t,
    xmltable('/NewDataSet/Table1'
        PASSING t.xml_ 
        columns 
            rowNo varchar2(10) path 'RowNo', 
            stfNo varchar2(10) path 'STF_N',
            modC varchar2(10) path 'MOD_C',
            coordTpC varchar2(10) path 'COORD_TP_C',
            coordRemark VARCHAR2(10) path 'COORD_REMARK'
    ) tt;
```

Result:

```
"ROWNO","STFNO","MODC" ,"COORDTPC","COORDREMARK"
"1"    ,"STF_1","MOD_1","COORD_1" ,"REMARK_1"
"2"    ,"STF_2","MOD_2","COORD_2" ,"REMARK_2"
"3"    ,"STF_3","MOD_3","COORD_3" ,"REMARK_3"
"4"    ,"STF_4","MOD_4","COORD_4" ,"REMARK_4"
```

Let me know in case you need more input. HTH

**Edit:** To answer the question below. Yes, no need to hard code. It is standard XQuery. If you replace `xmltable('/NewDataSet/Table1'` with `xmltable('/*/*'`, you get the same result. HTH

Comment: Would it be possible not to hardcode the `/NewDataSet/Table1` in the `xmltable` command? Because the string cannot be guaranteed to always be this one, I can only guarantee the structure will be the dataset then the table.

Comment: I get the following error when running your code : PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: hi @rcs this indicates you have put my demo-sql inside a begin-end block. the select is just a demo and is meant to run outside of pl/sql, to show you how `xmltable` could be used to solve your problem. you still need to write the pl/sql yourself. there is loads of good examples out there. Check out the first code block on this page for a simple example of using a table type with bulk collect into: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-bulk-collect. HTH